# jQuery - How do I get the image width of an online image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a project which consists of a HTML, JS and CSS file. 
When I open the project in my browser I have an input field (url input), a button and a canvas. 
After I insert the URL of an image in the input field and click the button, I want the canvas to resize according to the width and height of the image. Of course, I also want the image to be displayed in the canvas.
Note: Later I want to add a functionality where someone can resize the image with a slider. This means that I really have to save the width of the image in a variable.

So, my main problem is that I don't know how to get the width of that image.

The last thing I tried is the following:

```
$('#btn_load').click(function () {
      input_url = $('#input_url');
      var url = input_url.val();
      var img_width = url.width;
      ...
    });
```

Would be glad about some help here, since I tried a lot of stuff in the last hours :)

**EDIT:**

I now also tried the following:

```
var inputURL, imgWidth;

inputURL = $('#input_url');

$('#btn_load').click(function () {
      var url = inputURL.val();
      var img = new Image();
      img.src = url;
      img.onload = function () {
        imgWidth = img.width;
      };

      canvas.css({
        'background-image': 'url(' + url + ')',
        //'background-size': 'cover',
      });
      //This is just to check the width value
      inputURL.val(imgWidth + url);
    });
```

But still doesn't work.

Comment: Create an `img` element, give its `src` the value you have, and get its width once loaded.

Comment: Hey @chriskirknielsen I also tried that now, but it doesn't work. Would be glad if you have a look at my edit :)

Comment: You'll run into a race condition where the `imgWidth` variable is `undefined` when you call it. Place the code from below your `onload` block inside that `onload` function, that should help!

Comment: Ahhh, saw you comment a little bit too late. But thanks for your patience and help. I really appreciate it! :)

Comment: Glad you got your issue fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get the img width and height in the global variables 'imgHeight' and 'imgWidth' It will also display the image on the screen, width a slider to make it bigger or smaller,
the min and max value of the input type range are dynamically set to the original width and height divider by 2 or for the maximum multiplied by 2.

Javascript:

```
var imgHeight;
var imgWidth;
var img = new Image();

function LoadImage() {

    input_url = $('#input_url');
    img.src = input_url.val();
    //img.src = 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif';

    img.onload = function() {
        imgHeight = this.height;
        imgWidth = this.width;

        //alert(imgHeight + " : " + imgWidth);

        //Now set the image to html
        document.getElementById("imgID").src=img.src;

        //Now set the dimensions.
        $("#imgID").css({'height' : imgHeight+'px', 'width' : imgWidth+'px'});

        //Now set the range min to imgwidth / 2. and the max to imgwidth * 2 
        document.getElementById("range").min = imgWidth / 2;
        document.getElementById("range").max = imgWidth * 2;
        document.getElementById("range").value = imgWidth;
   }
}



function ChangeImageSize(value) {
    //Calculate new height so the image doesn't get stretched.
    newHeight = value / imgWidth * imgHeight;

    //Set the new width and height
    $("#imgID").css({'height' : newHeight+'px', 'width' : value+'px'}); 
}
```

HTML

```
 <button onclick="LoadImage()">click me</button>
 <input type="range" id="range" oninput="ChangeImageSize(this.value)">
 <input type="text" id="input_url">
 <img id="imgID">
```

Comment: Hey Niels, I implemented the part with `img.onload` until I reach the line `imgWidth = this.width;`. But the value that I am getting, when I print it in the text box is "undefined". Any idea, why this is not working?

Comment: I had an undefined aswell, until i put the code withing the img.onload = function() {}, are you sure the code is in there. And that the imgWidht is a global variable?

Comment: Hey Niels, I didn't put all the code from the `img.onload` (see my edit) but the the code I didn't put in there has nothing to do with the width being undefined, right?

Comment: You should still put it in the img.onload() {}, because you are trying to acces the imgWidth variable on the same function, but under the img.onload, the code is basically already executing before the image is loaded and the variable has been given a value

Comment: Oh maaaan, my error was to check the width of the image outside the `onload` function. Your code works perfectly fine! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You should load the imag to get its natural width and height :

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = $('#input_url').val();
img.onload = function () {
  imageWidth= img.naturalWidth;
  imageHeight = img.naturalHeight;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Hey rabsom, I think there is a `.val()` missing after the input_url. But unfortunately I still get the value "undefined" for the width, if I use your code snippet.

Comment: oups, it has been added. Thx Loeli ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <html>
 <head>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" > </script>

   <script>

   function loadUrl() {

    //You can get the value of your url_input and use it instead.
    var url = "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a"; //You can take it from your input_url
    $("#img-size").attr("src", url);


   };


     function imageLoaded(sender){
      alert($(sender).width() + 'x' + $(sender).height());
     }


  </script>

 </head>


<body>

 <img src="" id="img-size" onload="imageLoaded(this);">
 <input type="button" onclick="loadUrl();" id="btn_load" value="Load" />



</body>


</html>
```